# How to modify the margin in the footline of beamer?

Tags: beamer, header-footer

I am using Warsaw theme.

I want less space to be given to the author name part and more to the presentation title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just play with the numbers `wd=.3\paperwidth` and `wd=.7\paperwidth`

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\title{title}
\author{author names}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.3\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm plus1fill,rightskip=.3cm]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.7\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
 Something text here
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! That helps!