# How to change the footer of madrid theme in latex

Tags: beamer, themes, footer

I am using madrid theme in beamer using following code,

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\usecolortheme{beaver}
\usepackage{utopia} 
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multicol}



\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\title[Title]{Title}
%\author{M. Saiful Bari\inst{1} \and Mr X\inst{2}}
\author{My Name\inst{1}}
\institute{
    \inst{1}
     Sample University testing and testing
}

\date{20 June, 2017}

\begin{document}



\frame{\titlepage}


\section{test}


\end{document}
```

The following output is generated,

[image]

Here see that my "Name and Institution" at the footer is cut down. How to extend more position for "Name and Institution". I have seen many post regarding the customization. I am new to latex. Please provide comment while writing code so that I can customize the theme by myself.

Comment: Untested: Try `\author[Short Version]{Long Version}`. `Short Version` goes into the footer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically the same as [How to modify the margin in the footline of beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357678/how-to-modify-the-margin-in-the-footline-of-beamer/357679#357679)

Adjust the width of the three `beamercolorboxes` by modifying `wd=.4\paperwidth`, you just have to make sure that the sum of the widths still adds up to 1.

--

Some further comments:

- you don't need `graphicx`, as beamer already provides this functionality
- I don't see any justification to use `multicol` in beamer, as beamer has it's own environment for columns.
- if you look into your log file you will see that `utopia` gives the message `This package is to be regarded as obsolete.`

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\usecolortheme{beaver}
%\usepackage{utopia} 
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{multicol}



\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\title[Title]{Title}
%\author{M. Saiful Bari\inst{1} \and Mr X\inst{2}}
\author{My Name\inst{1}}
\institute{
    \inst{1}
     Sample University testing and testing
}

\date{20 June, 2017}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.4\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor\expandafter\ifblank\expandafter{\beamer@shortinstitute}{}{~~(\insertshortinstitute)}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.3\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.3\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}


\frame{\titlepage}


\section{test}


\end{document}
```